# When I use file.listFiles() on root path it always returns null

Tags: android

(Forgive my bad English)
I want to make a file explorer app on Android, but I cannot get file list on root path.
I develop with Android Studio 3.1.2, and I created a very basic app for test. 
 I already get the Read/Write storage permission in both manifest and code:

AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

MainActivity

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            readWritePermmisionRequestCode);
```

And I write a simple method to log the files from my app directory to the root path:

```
private void searchAllSubFiles() {
    if (targetFilePath.isEmpty()) targetFilePath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    try{
        File file = new File(targetFilePath);

        String msg = "Path:" + targetFilePath;
        msg += ", file name:" + file.getName();
        msg += ", file readable:" + file.canRead();
        msg += ", file writable:" + file.canWrite();
        msg += ", file is directory:" + file.isDirectory();
        msg += ", file can execute:" + file.canExecute();
        msg += ", sub files:" + file.listFiles();
        Log.d(TAG, msg);

        if (targetFilePath.equals("/"))return;

        targetFilePath = file.getParent();
        searchAllSubFiles();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can not read sub files.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here's the log:

```
Path:/data/user/0/com.test.xux.testviewer/files, file name:files, file readable:true, file writable:true, file is directory:true, file can execute:true, sub files:[Ljava.io.File;@70ac326
Path:/data/user/0/com.test.xux.testviewer, file name:com.test.xux.testviewer, file readable:true, file writable:true, file is directory:true, file can execute:true, sub files:[Ljava.io.File;@c6edb67
Path:/data/user/0, file name:0, file readable:false, file writable:false, file is directory:true, file can execute:true, sub files:null
Path:/data/user, file name:user, file readable:false, file writable:false, file is directory:true, file can execute:true, sub files:null
Path:/data, file name:data, file readable:false, file writable:false, file is directory:true, file can execute:true, sub files:null
Path:/, file name:, file readable:false, file writable:false, file is directory:true, file can execute:true, sub files:null
```

In fact, it works well in my app's directory. But in path /data/user/0 the file becomes unreadable and unwritable. I want my app being able to read all files in the phone just like another app PerfectViewer. What should I do?

Comment: You mean you want to display external storage directories or your internal app directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to read android os level directories which is not readable to end user in non rooted phone .

from your error log its clear .

this is your app's directory so  `file readable:true, file writable:true`

> Path:/data/user/0/com.test.xux.testviewer, file
>   name:com.test.xux.testviewer, file readable:true, file writable:true,
>   file is directory:true, file can execute:true, sub
>   files:[Ljava.io.File;@c6edb67

Now you are trying to read files on the root location which is not readable .

So its clear  in log that

```
 file readable:false, file writable:false
```

> Path:/data/user/0, file name:0, file readable:false, file
>   writable:false, file is directory:true, file can execute:true, sub
>   files:null

That's why its returning null.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if my app run on a rooted machine it can work well? I usually test my app on a virtual device can Android Studio be able to turn it into a rooted device?

Comment: it depends on your developement purpose . you are develeoping app for only rooted device ?

Comment: I also find another permission call MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, but when I add it to the manifest it says "Permission is only granted to system apps". Does that means if my app is an system app it can work on non rooted device just like the app "File Commander" on my non rooted Sony phone?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm not satisfied with Perfect Viewer's functions, so I want to make an app to read local comics.

Comment: you can read internal and external storage both . so whats the problem you're facing

Comment: Your answer already solved my problem, thanks again. Basicly I make the app only for my personal reason so it works on my rooted phone that is enough fine. I was just wondering if I can make for my friends' non rooted phone.